# Error: maxFieldsSize 2097152 exceeded error when trying to send base64 image through express

Tags: node.js, express, upload, base64, multer

Getting `Error: maxFieldsSize 2097152 exceeded` on express when trying to send a base64 image through axios with  "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data".

I tried using a couple of different middlewares:

```
app.use(bodyParser.text({ limit: '200mb' }));
app.use(express.json({
  limit: '500mb',
}));
app.use(express.bodyParser({
  uploadDir: require('os').tmpdir(),
  limit: '500mb',
}));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));
```

But I keep getting the same maxFieldsSize error.

Answer (score 0):

Adding maxFieldsSize as a argument on express.bodyParse fixed the issue!

```
app.use(express.bodyParser({
  uploadDir: require('os').tmpdir(),
  limit: '50mb',
  maxFieldsSize:'2 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 ',
}));
```